# What do I do when I get "error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bug/INC-4649' " while trying to git pull?

Tags: git

When I try to git pull, I get an error saying "error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bug/INC-4649': is at 6650f6fab0007ac84d7d9caebcaa819908993bfa but expected e537dd0de6ae15a8f44d1c2d8cf9d9e1ed965c55" from the endpoint.

Tried to git pull all changes

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this happens because on one side, you have a ref that is stored in the file system as a directory (e.g., `refs/remotes/origin/foo/bar`) and the other side has it as a file (e.g., `refs/heads/foo` on the server).  That can lead to a problem, since Git stores refs in the file system and can't have the same value as both a file and a directory.

The easiest way to solve this is `git remote prune origin`, which removes refs that don't exist, and then you can attempt your pull again.

If you do need to delete a ref manually for some reason, it's better to use `git update-ref` for this rather than deleting it manually, since it's much safer.  Note that because this is a plumbing (low-level) command, you'll need to specify the full name of the ref, so it would be `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/bug/INC-4649`.

It can also happen in some cases that these things can happen if you're storing your repository in a cloud syncing service, such as Dropbox or OneDrive, which definitely can cause corruption and other problems like this, so you should first move it out if you've configured it that way.

Answer (score -3):

In your terminal, enter '.git', and then 'open .'
By doing so, a parent folder will open up with refs as one of the sub-folders. Follow the path of the error by clicking on refs -> remotes -> origin -> bug and then delete the component that displays the error (if there are no relevant files in this folder, I would delete all of them and empty out the bug folder). Then 'cd ..' back to your branch and 'git pull'

Comment: You should never edit files within the .git folder. It's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: This is a dangerous thing to do. The problem is most likely hidden somewhere else (perhaps in wrong usage of git).